# Is it possible to create a new Firebase project by API?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools, firebase-console

**Is it possible to create new hosting projects by API, or another non-interactive method on Google Firebase?**

I already tried Firebase tools with a token, but it says that it is only possible to create a new project on Firebase Console.

*Some context*:
My project allows users to create static websites online and we are searching for solutions to host these sites. Firebase would be a great solution, but only if I could integrate the user's new project into my system, with Firebase projects.

Comment: did you succeed?
Firebase now allows you to add itself to a GCP project, but it has a small limit on the number of projects

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Updated** (2018-11-07)

It is now possible to create with the [Firebase Management API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/). Through this same API you can get a list of projects, add an app to an existing project, and list the apps in a project.

Comment: Do you know if it doesn't have one API, because it is not done yet, or if is there a reason to don't have one?

Comment: -- "... currently ..."

Comment: It's really too bad that Firebase doesn't have this in their public API, it seems vital because I have the need to spin up blank databases for automated CI and testing. I had been using https://github.com/casetext/firebase-admin but that seemed to have stopped working

Comment: Totally agree! In my case, I have to put people to create it manually.

Comment: hii @Frank van Puffelen, i also need to create Firebase project by Api. you answered before an year ago,then now after an year is this solved or not. Api available or not?

Comment: The situation is still the same. I know that some work has been done on creating an API for this, but there is no timeline on when (of even if) that may become available.

Comment: Is this possible using something like Admin sdk instead of over a restful api?

Answer (score 1):

- Hi!

  ```
  public static void AddFirebase()
   {
       var request = new AddFirebaseRequest();
       var operationFirebase1 = _firebaseManagementService.Projects.AddFirebase(request,
           "projects/" + CloudManager.ProjectId).Execute();
       WaitOperation(operationFirebase1, "Firebase");

   }
  ```

My sample creating a new Firebase project by API:https://github.com/Denys2211/Firebase-cloud-messaging