# How do I create a new project in Firebase through API?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

Is there is any API, which I can use to create a new project. I tried hard to find the google API but couldn't get any. 
Also I tired GCM (google cloud messaging) but that too redirect to Firebase and the Firebase forcing me to create a project manually.

In my scenario I have more than 1000 APK I need to integrate with the Firebase and it's likely a not good idea do manually and also it gonna take my more resource.

Comment: Please, check this question and its answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37797334/is-possible-create-new-firebase-project-by-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: See [Firebase Management API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/)

<s>Unfortunately, there is no API available that creates Firebase Projects.</s>

A Firebase Project is required when using GCM/FCM, since it is only through the Firebase Console, will you get the Server Key which is needed for Authorization.