# FCM for Android using programmatically

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have done everything with FCM console for push notification and its working fine. I am also getting push notifications on device but according my need I  create project programmatically using java code so is there any API for that or we have to done this manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no public API to create Firebase projects. As the tools/CLI says, you'll have to create them in the Firebase Console.

You can refer to this link : 
[Is possible create new firebase project by API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37797334/is-possible-create-new-firebase-project-by-api)

Comment: thanks! this is the proper answer of my question.

Comment: Your welcome always