# How to go about GCM to FCM migration for multiple apps having same sender IDs

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have multiple android apps with same sender IDs (single google console project).

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11587181

Now that it's mandatory to migrate to `FCM`, I have two questions:

1. `GCM` to `FCM` migration docs recommends importing the old project into firebase console. How do I go about this since multiple apps are linked to the same project and firebase console requires one project per app?
2. Is there an API to create firebase project instead of using the firebase console to create projects for each app manually?

Update: 
 Question 2 is duplicate, but as per discussions in the comments this question boils down to 'Is there an API to add apps to a firebase project'.

Comment: *firebase console requires one project per app?* - does it?

Comment: As soon as you create a project in firebase console, there is section called add firebase to your app which basically gives you `google-services.json`. This step asks for a package name and you can only add one package name, hence the above conclusion. Do let me know if I am wrong and if there is a workaround to use the same project for multiple  apps.

Comment: On https://console.firebase.google.com/ you can go to project settings and there is an option to add multiple apps to the project

Comment: You can indeed only add one package name per Android app, but you can have multiple apps per project. There is no API to create projects. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37797334/is-possible-create-new-firebase-project-by-api

Comment: Thanks @TimCastelijns, there is indeed an option in project settings.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: thanks for the response. Would have made life much easier if there was an API. Will keep following that question if you happen to update it in near future.